# Trello API, Want to get all Cards that contains customFields with specific Value

Tags: c#, api, trello

Have a question that i hope you might help, 
I have a trello board that contains my cards.Each cards contains CustomFields and Each Custom fields contains some value.
I want to query the API and get all cards that contains the custom field value let's say "FOO".
is there a way to do as i want it ?

My problem is i cant find any routes on the API to get what i want 
the only routes that i found is to get first only get all cards with this query 
https://api.trello.com/1/boards/t1Wtqf63/cards/?fields=name&customFieldItems/5a9866f7d6afbd6de1bc1039&customFieldItems/5a9866f7d6afbd6de1bc1037&customFieldItems/5a9866f7d6afbd6de1bc103b&key=9f305ab66ae25df1dc68521ada32793a&token=1a48028e7d91fa6bcb59aed736287cf084e368ae5d0991a4635fac1c51f0bdf8
then 
parse the json returned and then https://api.trello.com/1/cards/59a419628f90b0113f6d4dd9/customFieldItems?key=9f305ab66ae25df1dc68521ada32793a&token=1a48028e7d91fa6bcb59aed736287cf084e368ae5d0991a4635fac1c51f0bdf8
get all customFields values
what i want is to simplify thoes query and do it it one query.
I am using HTTP web request to get to the trello  API and the language of programming that i use for my software is c# 
Thanks for your response

Comment: Where are you getting the problem? What have you got so far? Paste us your code. https://developers.trello.com/reference#custom-fields-object

Comment: updated my post with my queries

Comment: waiting for the trello support's answer